# Difference of two solutions of system of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\mathrm{p}_1 = (\alpha_1, \beta_1, \gamma_1)$   and $\mathrm{p}_2 = (\alpha_2, \beta_2, \gamma_2)$ be two particular solutions of a non-homogeneous system of linear equations. Give an example for a solution of corresponding homogeneous system.

The solutions set of a given system $\mathrm{Ax}=\mathrm{b}$ can be described as $\mathrm{p}_i +\mathrm{v}$, where $\mathrm{p}_i$ is a unique solution for a specific $\mathrm{b}_i$ in $\mathrm{Ax}=\mathrm{b}_i$, and $\mathrm{v}$ is a solution of the corresponding $\mathrm{Ax}=\mathrm{0}$ system. However, I don't really understand why $\mathrm{p}_2-\mathrm{p}_1 = (\alpha_2 - \alpha_1, \beta_2 - \beta_1, \gamma_2 - \gamma_1)$ is a possible solution of the corresponding homogeneous system. Because, when taking difference, we apparently "lose" the $\mathrm{v}$ component (which suppose to be the solution of the homogeneous system).

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, let $p_1$ and $p_2$ be two particular solutions to $Ax=b$ (so that $Ap_1=b$ and $Ap_2=b$). The problem is to show that $A(p_2-p_1) = 0$, which means that $p_2-p_1$ solves the corresponding homogeneous system. We have:

$$A(p_2-p_1) = Ap_2 - Ap_1 = b - b = 0.$$

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to interpret this property geometrically? I.e., the reason that we have (at least) two solutions meaning that there is infinite number of solutions for $Ax=b$. If there is only one $df$, the solution is represented by a straight line in $\mathbb{R}^3$, hence the difference is simply another point on that line?

Comment: @user230329 I don't quite understand your question. Can you rephrase?

Comment: Specifically, we have $3\times 3$ matrix, i.e., 3 equations and 3 variables. Hence, assuming that $\mathrm{rank}(A|b)=\mathrm{rank}(A)=2$, so the solution exists and it must be a straight line which is the intersection of two planes. Hence, the given two solutions are just two (random) points on that line? If so, we can say that the difference is simply another point on that line?

Comment: @user230329 If $\text{rank}(A|b) = 2$, then the solution set of $Ax=b$ is indeed a straight line, but it is not a straight line that goes through the origin. The line has been shifted. Since $Ap_1=b$ and $Ap_2=b$, then $p_1$ and $p_2$ are two points on this shifted line, but their difference will not be on the same line. Rather, their difference is a point on the solution set to $Ax=b$, which is a line through the origin. In short, $p_1$ and $p_2$ are points on the shifted straight line, while $p_2-p_1$ is a point on the parallel straight line through the origin.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, suppose $p_{1}$ and $p_{2}$ are two distinct solutions of $Ax=b$. You have, by definition of a solution:

$$\begin{cases}
Ap_{1}&=b\\
Ap_{2}&=b
\end{cases}$$

Then, you have directly 
$$\begin{align}
Ap_{1}&=Ap_{2}\\
Ap_{1}-Ap_{2}&=0\\
A(p_{1}-p_{2}) &=0\tag{because of the linearity of $A$}
\end{align}$$

It explicitly means that $p_{1}-p_{2}$ is a solution of the homogeneous system $Ax=0$ associated with $Ax=b$.